# Haloalkenes selectivity of reagents

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

5-chloro-1, 3 - dimethylcyclohexene is the substrate. I understand that hydroboration oxidation occurs in 2 steps the first being addition of Boron as an electrophile and the second being oxidation by peroxide ion. Since the solution now contains Hydroxide ion  now this will attack the carbon bonded to chlorine by SN2 mechanism. But in my book , in the final product chlorine is not replaced with OH. I don't understand why.

Comment: You assume that the peroxide/base reaction and an SN2 reaction have similar rates. Moreover, E2 elimination is also a real possibility rather than displacement of chlorine.

Comment: What solvent is the reaction run in?

Comment: @Waylander I don't know I just started learning organic chemistry and this question appears with the substrate and an arrow on which B2H6 and OH-, H2O2 are written. Maybe the question is ill posed.

Comment: @user55119 2° carbon and SN2/E2  conditions  elimination product will be major right? Why this was down voted I will edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: My point, as Waylander has noted, is that the basic peroxide oxidation is faster (often needs cooling) than an SN2 reaction with hydroxide. The SN2 reaction on a halocyclohexane will compete with an E2 reaction. It's all about conditions (relative rates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH- is not that great a nucleophile for a secondary chloride.

If we assume an ethereal solvent, most likely THF, much of the OH- will be in aqueous phase and not available to react with the product in the organic phase.
If the reaction is kept cool (as it should be) E2 is unlikely to be a major pathway hence the product is 5-chloro-1,3-dimethylcyclohexan-2-ol

Comment: Why this  reaction should be kept cool?

Comment: The oxidative work up is exothermic. If it gets too hot pathways like E2 or OH- attack can become relevant.